# jQuery click method returning undefined when iterating over array nested in object nested in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Why does the click method return undefined after the for in loop iterates over the first array of answer objects?

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

var allQuestions = [{question:"What is the color of the sky?",answer:["blue","yellow",  
                "red"],correctAnswer:["blue",1]},{question:"What is the opposite of  
                 up?",answer:["down","sideways", "circle"],correctAnswer:["down",1]},
                {question:"What is the first number?",answer:["1","5", "7"],correctAnswer:
                ["1",1]}];

$(document).ready(function() {  

    function changeQuestion() {
        $("#radios").empty();
        for( answers in allQuestions[i].answer) {
            var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" class="radios" name="btnAnswers" value="'+ 
                allQuestions[i].answer[j] + '" /><label for ="secondbtn">'
                + allQuestions[i].answer[j] + '</label>');
            radioBtn.appendTo('#radios');
            alert(allQuestions[i].answer[j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        return true;
    };

    $("#nextbtn").click(function(){
        changeQuestion();
    });
});
```

[This question's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stw/zu9e5poh/)

Comment: Where are `i` and `j` initialized?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Sorry, didn't add them in the initial post. They are there now but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `.answer` property of the objects is an array, you can loop with

```
for(var j=0; allQuestions[i].answer.length; j++) {...}
```

instead of

```
for(answers in allQuestions[i].answer) {...}
```

Full code will be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    function changeQuestion() {
        $("#radios").empty();
        var obj = allQuestions[i];
        for(var j=0; j<obj.answer.length; j++) {
            $('<input type="radio" class="radios" name="btnAnswers" value="' + obj.answer[j] + '" /><label for ="secondbtn">' + obj.answer[j] + '</label>').appendTo('#radios');
        }
        i++;
    };
    $("#nextbtn").click(changeQuestion);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zu9e5poh/10/

Comment: Thanks this worked! Can you explain (or provide links ) why the "for in" loop returned undefined on the second run of changeQuestion?

Comment: Your `for(... in ...)` construction isn't actually the culprit. It's the `j` counter, which keeps on incrementing, so on the second run, it will start at 3. If you were to move `var j = 0` inside `changeQuestion()`, then it will be reset to zero at the start of every run. In my version, `for(var j=0; ...)` has exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize values to variables i & j

modify the code to

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
function changeQuestion() {
$("#radios").empty();

var  i=0, j=0;

for( answers in allQuestions[i].answer) {
    var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" class="radios" name="btnAnswers" value="'+ 
                    allQuestions[i].answer[j] + '" /><label for ="secondbtn">' 
            + allQuestions[i].answer[j] + '</label>');
    radioBtn.appendTo('#radios');
    alert(allQuestions[i].answer[j]);
 j++;
}
 i++;
 return true;
};
$("#nextbtn").click(function(){
    changeQuestion();
 });
```

});

Comment: @MJD I added the initialization and array in the fiddle, as well as an alert to show how the code steps but it's not working still.